# IP camera stream in web page

Tags: python, video, ip-camera, simplecv

I trying to make a simple security system based on my IP camera, where my computer will be the server. Currently I'm using mongoose as the server and SimpleCV to capture the video.
My goal (for now) is to create a live stream on a web page so I can access it remotely.

So far I managed to access mongoose remotely, and get the video stream (MJPEG) in a window, but I can't manage to stream the video to a web page, and I can't find any examples in the SimpleCV forum. Is it even possible to do such a thing?

This is how I'm currently streaming the video

```
from SimpleCV import JpegStreamCamera, Display
import time

cam = JpegStreamCamera('http://name:pass@xx.xx.xx.xx/streampath')

display = Display()
img = cam.getImage()
img.save(display)
while not display.isDone():

    img = cam.getImage()
    img.drawText(time.ctime())
    img.save(display)
    time.sleep(1)
```

To run in a browser I tried the following but nothing happened (blank page)

```
from SimpleCV import *
import webbrowser
import time

js = JpegStreamer()
webbrowser.open(js.url())
cam = JpegStreamCamera('http://name:pass@xx.xx.xx.xx/streampath')

while True:
    img = cam.getImage()
    img.save(js)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

even if that worked I wouldn't know how to embed it into a working web page (maybe in an iframe?...)

Any help will be appreciated.